# Ubuntu/ Benchmarking localhost (be patient)...apr_socket_recv: Connection refused (111)

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, benchmarking, apachebench

I learning about Nodejs cluster, And when I try to test my app with apache, I got this error.

```
usama@usama:~/Learn/back-end/advance-nodejs/section two$ ab -c 50 -n 500 localhost:5000/fast
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1843412 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)
apr_socket_recv: Connection refused (111)
```

Answer (score 0):

Start nodejs server before `ab -c 50 -n 500 localhost:5000/fast`